# Navigation bar on a website

Tags: website-design, navigation

I've designed a website that uses a navigation bar. On this bar there is a tab called "Contact" and it has two further options "Private" and "Office".

My question is whether I should include the navigation pane or bar on all these pages or could I just use it for the homepage and "Contact" page while using a breadcrumb trial for the pages "Private" and "Office". Will it affect usability?

Comment: What will be on the "Private" and "Office" pages? If they contain additional contact information, why not include everything on the "Contact" page and eliminate the other two? The less clicks the user needs to find the information they're looking for, the better!

Comment: Yes,but let's say this is the structure we are supposed to follow. Then would it be alright using breadcrumb trials?

Comment: What software stack are you using for this site? Is there a version we can see?

Answer (score 1):

Most sites have a navigation pane at the top or one side of the site. The standard is to have navigation on every page.

Two common exception to this rule are:

- **Marketing Landing Pages:** Pages reached from outside of the site where you want the visitor to perform a specific action (buying something, signing up for emails, etc) before reaching the main site.
- **Purchase Processing Steps:** Pages in a shopping cart system often leave off navigation once the user starts checking out their order. This is to minimize the likelihood they'll get side-tracked onto another page and never finish their purchase.

Comment: Thank you all. Looks like having the navigation bar will be a better option.

Comment: Be sure to mark the best answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I would **definitely keep the navigation bar on every page** as it makes navigation for the user not only easier, but more accessible. Using breadcrumbs is nice if the user wants to see where they came from, but overall it requires more work for the user to figure out which breadcrumb they wish to return to and if the page they wish to go to is not on the breadcrumb navigation area then they would have to return to the homepage and look through the navigation bar which simply creates **more work than necessary**. Stick with the navigation bar on every page to make your site more user friendly.